Select a constant value using same SQL statement in SQL Server and Oracle
I need to write a query which will be run against SQL Server and Oracle. A query just selects a constant.
In SQL Server, I can do this:
SELECT 1 AS Value;

And in Oracle:
SELECT 1 AS Value FROM DUAL;

But the database is not known at runtime. Is it possible to have one SQL query for both DBMS?
Queries above work fine, but I need to unify the syntax.

Even for simple statements, sometimes consistency between different products is but a dream.

For what versions of Oracle? I did submit an answer suggesting table valued constructors but seems that support for that is much the same or identical to support for "SELECT Without FROM Clause" anyway! https://oracle-base.com/articles/23/select-without-from-clause-23

But as SQL Server doesn't support DUAL and Oracle doesn't support information_schema there will possibly be no common "out of the box" object that can be referenced in a FROM so you'll probably be out of luck unless you create one

Martin Smith, it's enterprise, either 19c or 21c, not 23ai.

You'll probably need to create a dummy table with one row that can be available in both databases you can use for this purpose. But generally speaking you will NOT be successful building an application that can run on multiple database types with only one set of SQL. There are too many dialect differences that will trip you up.

I invariably have some sort of Date Dimension or Calendar or sequency table on my databases and can recommend having something similar.  In which case I would use SELECT rn FROM CalSeq WHERE rn = 1 but any table common to both environments would work if you have given it a row number and it is sequential, starting at 1.  I have more than one row because I might want a number bigger than 1! @JoelCoehoorn makes an excellent point though - too many dialect differences - just take the hit OR consider using Linked tables?

My final solution was to use an existing table with very few records and limiting result to first row only. As I have to support Oracle 21c at least.

For Oracle 23c the "From Dual" could be omitted and
Select 1 as CONST

would work in both databases
For older Oracle versions one  way to do it is to create dual table in SQL Server
create table Dual (dummy Char(1));
Insert Into Dual Values('x');

... after this
Select 1 as CONST From Dual;

would work in both databases
But that all doesn't make much sense since there are so many other differencies.

Possible solution but instead of managing additional temp table chose to use an existing table as a dummy.

@Vy8 To be honest, I don't see the solution here for all the differencies in sintax. This creates permanent table Dual (not temp) to satisfy the condition that same code (Select 1 as CONST From Dual) fetches a constant value. I don't know if any existing table with same name already exist in both OP's SQL Server and Oracle databases...
